# Slack silently copying clipboard?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, slack

I'm running Slack desktop on an Intel Macbook pro running macOS Ventura 13.5.1.

Sometimes when I switch the focus back to Slack I see a dialog popup along the lines of `Pasting from XXX's Macbook`.

I did not hit Ctrl+V, I did not right-click and select paste and no pasted text appears anywhere in Slack.

It seems as if Slack is "silently" copying my clipboard. I have come across one other report of this behaviour: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/xqgfeg/slack_for_mac_silently_copying_clipboard_contents/

I'm not sure if this related to Apple's continuity feature in someway.

I'd like to understand what is going on and, if possible, disable whatever is causing the issue.

Comment: What do the Slack developers have to say about this?

Comment: The odd thing is not that it has access to the clipboard - all apps have access to the clipboard, it's not a private or sandboxed structure - but that it's specifically telling you it's going to paste… then doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the response I received from Slack

> During sign in, we copy a fallback sign in key to the user's clipboard and when the app is focussed, we check for this key in case the handoff between the user's browser and our app fails for some reason. We do have some work underway to refine this clipboard read so it has less of an impact to our users.

> If you'd like to disable this function, you can enter the following into your browser's URL bar and hit enter, which will turn off the clipboard read:
> slack://setting/?update=isClipboardReadDisabled:true

I have entered the URL to disable the clipboard, so I wait and see I guess.